# Three values in cookie(s)

Tags: javascript, php

When a user visits my website he/she has to select a location from the list of available cities. I want to save his/her last three choices in cookie(s).
It is not necessary to save all three values in single cookie but I want to know best practice to do so.

My Questions are:

1. How to **set** last three cities as cookie(s) in **javascript**.
2. How to **get** last three cities as cookie(s) in **php**.

Currently my Javascript function is

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, exdays) {   /*number of days until the cookie should expire (exdays)*/
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; " + expires;
}
```

In java script I set cookie like this

```
setCookie(cityName, cityValue, 360)
```

and i am getting cookie in php using

```
echo $_COOKIE[cityName];
```

Comment: have you tried session variables to store the selection ?

Comment: what you have tried so far? where is code?

Comment: Have you Googled “set cookies javascript” and “get cookies php” already?

Comment: `document.cookie` in javascript and `$_COOKIE` in php

Comment: The answers to the questions of how to set and get cookies should be on Stack Overflow and several other sites already. Your unique problem seems to be the selection and display of cities. However your question doesn’t describe specifically how and when the cities should be selected or displayed. And it’s not our job to design a user interface for that purpose and write all the code. That’s actually your job. In your case, we’d just help with specific problems with _existing non-working code_.

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a array

```
var cookie1 = ['city1', 'city2', 'city3'];

var serialized = JSON.stringify( cookie1 );
```

now save this cookie

While fetching back user

> JSON.parse()

to get the array back

Comment: The questions were how to set and get the cookies. You answered with “now save this cookie”. How is this useful?

Comment: @Xufox question was 'How to set last three cities as cookie(s) in javascript' and not in general 'How to get/set cookies?' in general.

Comment: @gurvinder372 your answer helped me a lot.